# Python - Best way to use several tuple values in a for loop

Tags: python-2.7, tuples

Is there a better, more efficient way to use several tuple values in a for loop? For example, I have a list of tuples I am iterating through and each one of those tuples has several values:

```
values = [(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j), (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j)]

for a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j in values:
    do this......
```

Is there a more efficient, pythonic way to do handle a task like this without using so many iterators? I am still a bit new to Python (and coding in general). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you are trying to do, but I would:

```
for value in values:
    do this.....
    #refer to each element as value[0], value[1]...
```

Comment: Actually this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!